# Entity Framework code first - How to define a custom navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, navigation-properties

I'm using ASP.NET core and Entity Framework

I have a pre-existing database schema, and I want to add a linked table using a foreign key, however the foreign key index column isn't something that adheres to any of the standard EF conventions. How can I express this in Ef? I'd prefer to use Data Annotation attributes if possible, but perfectly fine to use the ModelBuilder fluent API if not.

Essentially this:

```
[Table("widgets")]
class Widget {
  [Key, Column("id")]
  int Id { get; set; }

  [Column("referencenumber")]
  int ReferenceNumber { get; set; }

  public WidgetReferenceData ReferenceData // ???? How do I express this?
}

[Table("widgetreferences")]
class WidgetReference {
  [Key, Column("referencenumber")]
  int ReferenceNumber { get; set; }

  [Column("value")]      
  string Value { get;set; }
}
```

In the above model, A `Widget` may have zero or one associated entry in the  `WidgetReference` table, linked using the `widgets.referencenumber` database column.

What I'd like to do is add a property to my Widget model to go and load this associated WidgetReference (or null if there's not one present). Basically I want to be able to use it like this:

```
var referenceValue = FindWidget().ReferenceData?.Value;
```

If it were a conventional "Id" column, EF would take care of it, but as I have custom database column and property names, how do I express this relation?

I'm not sure it affects the outcome, but it's critical that `widgetreferences.referencenumber` is NOT a foreign key, but rather just a column with an index on it. Our business logic is such that if a Widget gets deleted, we still want to retain the reference data

I've tried and failed to find the answer to this via Googling, but it feels like something that shouldn't be hard :-(

Comment: Title says it's code first, but body says it's DB first? If you scaffold it, how does the scaffolder represent your relation? (Or does it not bother because you have no FK?) what's the x:y relationship of widget and reference?

Comment: It's code first. I'm not using an edmx mapping file or anything like that.
The relationship is that Widget has zero or one References (join on the "referencenumber" column), but that a Reference will survive the Widget being deleted

Comment: Like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35501552/code-first-of-ef-how-to-define-navigation-property-relationship-without-setting ? General consensus on these things seems to be to let EF create the FK, then delete it from the DB. I suppose if it's keyed the right way round, you can try change it so it's a "set null on cascade delete" kind, so your reference loses its widgetid (but it looks like you're trying to relate the opposite way, and make widget have a referenceid, rather than reference having a widgetid) if the widget goes away

Answer (score 1):

```
    [Table("widgets")]
    class Widget 
   {
      [Key, Column("id")]
      int Id { get; set; }

      [Column("referencenumber")]
      int? ReferenceNumber { get; set; }

      [ForeignKey("ReferenceNumber")]
      public virtual WidgetReferenceData ReferenceData // ???? How do I express this?
    }

    [Table("widgetreferences")]
    class WidgetReference 
    {
      [Key, Column("referencenumber")]
      int ReferenceNumber { get; set; }

      [Column("value")]      
      string Value { get;set; }
    }
```

Just use the ForeignKeyAttribute to associate the Navigation Property with the Foreign Key Property.  EF doesn't care if there is actually a Foreign Key in the back-end.

Comment: It seems that regardless of whether I put a `[ForeignKey("ReferenceNumber")]` in the model or not, EF generates a database migration which adds an explicit foreign key between WidgetReference and Widget, which is not what I want.

Comment: If you have an existing database schema, you shouldn't be using migrations at all.

Comment: My existing database schema was generated using previous migrations in the past... All I want to do is express a business requirement  (optional extra data which is associated via a secondary key) without breaking all the existing data

Comment: Again, if you don't want EF modifying your database, don't use migrations.  Just manage your database schema separately.

Comment: I *do* want EF modifying my database, I'm just trying to figure out how to tell EF to modify it in the correct way (which doesn't seem to actually be possible in this instance, at least not today)